# Find the points $x>0$ where $x^x$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f(x)=x^x$ such that $0<x$.

Find the points $0<x$ where the function is differentiable and find the derive in those points.

$$x^x=e^{\ln x^x}=e^{x\ln x}$$

Because $e^x$ is differentiable for all $x$ and $x\ln x$ differentiable for $0<x$ can we conclude that it is differentiable for all $0<x$?

Or we should use the definition of the derivative?

And the derivative is $$x^x(\ln x+1)$$

Comment: Your proof is correct. Since it's a composition of two functions that are differentiable on the domain, it is differentiable by the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Using the equation $x^x=e^{x\ln x}$ the problem is much simpler that by definition of the derivative of the function. You only have to notice that the functions $g(x)=x\ln(x)$ and $f(x)=e^x$ are both differentiable for all $x>0$ so, by the chain rule the derivative of $f(g(x))$ exists for all $x>0$ and the derivative is $x^x(1+\ln x)$